# What this error means and how to fix it? `Constructing a IO::Async::Stream with an encoding-enabled handle may not read correctly`

Tags: perl, unicode

When I do:

```perl
use IO::Async::Stream;
$tty =  IO::Async::Stream->new(
    read_handle  =>  \*STDIN,
    write_handle =>  \*STDOUT,
    on_read      =>  \&tty_read,
);
```

I get error: `Constructing a IO::Async::Stream with an encoding-enabled handle may not read correctly`

On other host same code works fine.

Why on this host I get this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. This is different host and only environment could differ. So I did:

```
# env | grep PERL
PERL_UNICODE=SA
PERL5LIB=/usr/local/proj/lib:/usr/local/proj/local/lib/perl5:
```

Then I did `$ unset PERL_UNICODE` and my script works fine now.

See documentation [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#PERL_UNICODE) about `PERL_UNICODE`

Comment: `$ENV{PERL_UNICODE} = 0` might be less invasive that changing your shell env.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that IO::Async::Stream expects a "raw" file handle, but you are providing one with an encoding layer attached.

You might be using the following:

```perl
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

If so, replace it with the following:

```perl
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';
BEGIN { 
   binmode( STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)' );
}
```

To deal with decoded text, you'll also need to decode or encode the data received from and passed to `$tty`, say by using the `encoding` constructor parameter. You can't simply pass the text received by `on_read` to `decode` as it might contain a partial character.